# Why is "if s, ok := it.(TaggerShape); ok {" and "else if s, ok := it.(TaggerShape); ok {" in the same function?

Tags: go

Isn't this code repeating the same call twice? I am new to go, so this is most likely my own misunderstanding.

```golang
func Tag(it Shape, tag string) Shape {
    if s, ok := it.(TaggerShape); ok {
        s.AddTags(tag)
        return s
    } else if s, ok := it.(TaggerShape); ok {
        s.AddTags(tag)
        return s
    }
    return NewSave(it, tag)
}
```

It is from here: https://github.com/cayleygraph/cayley/blob/275a7428fb10fdb4d1167f09a7120898239903dd/graph/iterator/save.go#L14-L23

Comment: Just looks like a refactoring mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's duplicated. You can remove the `else if` block:

```golang
func Tag(it Shape, tag string) Shape {
    if s, ok := it.(TaggerShape); ok {
        s.AddTags(tag)
        return s
    }

    return NewSave(it, tag)
}
```

So just you know what `it.(TaggerShape)` means, from the spec:

> For an expression x of interface type and a type T, the primary
> expression
>
> x.(T) asserts that x is not nil and that the value stored in x is of
> type T. The notation x.(T) is called a type assertion.
>
> More precisely, if T is not an interface type, x.(T) asserts that the
> dynamic type of x is identical to the type T. In this case, T must
> implement the (interface) type of x; otherwise the type assertion is
> invalid since it is not possible for x to store a value of type T. If
> T is an interface type, x.(T) asserts that the dynamic type of x
> implements the interface T.